# How to display posts by category in a static page on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, post, categories, display

do you know which code should I use to display posts by category in a static page?

```
<div>
// This is a static page


// Here I want to display posts from specific category ex. category named hello


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Complete Implementation for fetching the post from a Specific Category and Display the post in a pages layout if you have more post.

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'category_name' => ‘your category’,
    'paged' => $paged,
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();?>
            <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                <h5><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></h5>
                <div>
                   <?php if( has_excerpt() ): the_excerpt(); else: the_content(); endif; ?>
                </div>
            <?php  }?>
    //Page navigation
        <div id="pagenav" class="navigation clearfix">
            <div class="nav-prev alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( '<i class="fa fa-angle-double-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-prev alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>' ); ?></div>
        </div><!-- #pagenav -->
        <?php echo '</div>';

     } else {
        // no posts found
        echo '<h1>No Posts Found</h1>';
    }

    // Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you but can you tell me how to make this section here with a variable https://prnt.sc/jyawtd because I have a category for every page and I want the category posts will display if the page have the same category like I have page 1 which have category 1 so when I want the posts from category 1 to be displaying in page 1 and if I have another page which is page 2 and it have a category 2 so I want the posts from category 2 to be displaying in the page 2

Comment: To make it simple look here https://prnt.sc/jyayir if I created a new page and then checked one of these categories I want the posts from the checked category to be displaying in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
[display-posts category="fishing,hiking"]
```

There are lots of other arguments you can give. This link will be useful: https://en.support.wordpress.com/display-posts-shortcode/

Comment: Thank you but your code work only with Wordpress.com not with the default wordpress framework :)